# standard mollifier (comparing the definition in Evans and wiki)

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Hi I am looking at the definition of standard mollifier $\eta$ in Evans,
[image]

and the $\eta$ from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier)

Have a very basic question, is the $\eta$ in Evans also compactly supported? i.e. $\eta\in C_c^{\infty}$?

Comment: yes. The support is $\{x:|x|\le 1\}$

Comment: Why does Evans claim $\operatorname{supp}(\eta_\epsilon) \subset B(0, \epsilon)$? Shouldn't it be $\operatorname{supp}(\eta_\epsilon) \subset \overline{B(0, \epsilon)}$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just look at the definition: since $\eta(x)=0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^N$ with $|x| \geq 1$, it follows that $\operatorname{supp}\eta \subset \overline{B(0,1)}$. Hence $\eta \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^N)$.