# Prove that the Friedrichs' mollifier has an integral equal to 1

Tags: functional-analysis

Prove that the following:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\eta_{\epsilon}(x)dx=1~\forall\epsilon>0$$
Where $\eta_{\epsilon}(x)$ is the Friedrichs' mollifier:
$$\eta_{\epsilon}(x)= \frac{1}{\epsilon^n}\eta(\frac{x}{\epsilon}) =\left\{\begin{matrix}
        \frac{1}{\epsilon^n}e^{\frac{1}{|\frac{x}{\epsilon}|^2-1}} & x<1\\
        \\
        0 & |x|\geq 1\\
        \end{matrix}\right.
        $$
and $\eta(x)$ is:
$$\eta(x) =\left\{\begin{matrix}
        e^{\frac{1}{|x|^2-1}} & x<1\\
        \\
        0 & |x|\geq 1\\
        \end{matrix}\right.
        $$
Im kind of lost as I do not know where to begin, the only thing that I did prove is that $\eta_{\epsilon}(x)$ has a compact support on $\overline{B_{\epsilon}(0)}$ and that it is $C^{\infty}$. Other than that I am kind of lost.

Comment: Do you know why it suffices to check that $\eta(x)$ has integral equal to $1$?

Comment: I would suppose that it is sufficient as $\eta_{\epsilon}(x)$ is an escalation (I don't know if that is correctly said, though I don't know how to translate the word I have in my mother language) of the function $\eta(x)$. In other words, it would be practically the same function but with a change of variables and a scalar multiplying it

Comment: Where do you see this definition? Do you miss a normalization constant in $\eta$? See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier#Concrete_example

Comment: I saw the definition of $\eta_{\epsilon}(x)$ on my course of Spectral Theory, And I'm not missing a normalization constant in $\eta$. I have been thinking and reading my notes, and the thing is that $\eta$ is just a function in $C_{0}^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with a compact support, but it is not a mollifier yet. When I compose it to the function $\eta_{\epsilon}(x)$ then it becomes a mollifier and the normalization constant is $\frac{1}{\epsilon^n}$. So I'm still stuck, as I don't know where to begin to prove the proposition, as the function does not have an obvious antiderivative.

Comment: The important part is that $\eta$ is smooth, positive, has the stated compact support, and has finite integral. Also your $\eta_\epsilon$ is incorrect … its support is  $(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$.

Comment: @adrinmajestuosso: $\eta$ is a special case of $\eta_\epsilon$ where $\epsilon=1$. It must be that $\int \eta=1$ if you have $\int \eta_\epsilon=1$ for all $\epsilon$. Moreover, $\frac{1}{\epsilon^n}$ is not the normalization constant, but due to a change of variables. I would not see your reply in time unless you ping me using `@Louis Pan` in the comment box.

Comment: I dint think this is true without a normalizing constant. Note that $0\leq \eta \leq 1$ and that $\eta$ is supported in the n-dimensional unit ball. The measure of this ball goes to zero with $n\to\infty$.

Comment: The mollifier needs to be defined with a constant in front obviously, which is actually some sort of hypergeometric function, [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1366268/standard-mollifier-comparing-the-definition-in-evans-and-wiki). Is the calculation of this integral of interest to you?

Comment: @DinosaurEgg Thank you very much. I do have an interest in the calculation of this integral, though I think I can calculate it with a change to spherical coordinates. I haven't tried it, but today I was going to try and solve it.

Comment: I think that I have the answer and will update the post at a later date, as I am busy right now.